# How to remove a specific class on the clicked control?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to remove a specific class on the clicked control, in particular I've this html structure:

```
<div id="resource">
   <div class="selected"></div>
   <div class="selected"></div>
</div>
```

this is my code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.selected', function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
  $(this).removeClass('selected'); //remove the specific class
} else
{
  $('#resource .selected').removeClass('selected'); //remove class of all control
$(this).addClass('selected'); //add class to the clicked control
}
});
```

and this is the css class:

```
.selected {
 background-color: red;
}
```

How you can see if I click on a div the class is added correctly, but if I've a div with `.selected` class already set and click on the div without this class the code doesn't remove the class of other div. Why??

this is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpw3w6w4/).

Comment: The else won't ever be executed because once you click the div with the selected class, the class is removed. Clicking it a second time won't run the jQuery since it's tied to the selected class.

Comment: You mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpw3w6w4/1/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click event works for only for `.selected` class. You should use `#resource div` click instead of `.selected`. Try like following.

```
$(document).on('click', '#resource div', function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
   } else
   {
      $('#resource .selected').removeClass('selected'); 
      $(this).addClass('selected');
   }
});
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/azim101/Lpw3w6w4/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="resource">
   <div class="container"></div>
   <div class="container"></div>
</div>   


 $(document).on('click', '.container', function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    })
```

change ur 'selected' div class names to 'container' or watever u want.
add click listener for those divs having 'container' or whatever name u hav given for tat div

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more simple by adding an extra class. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q369fxuw/). The error is that the selected class gets removed. Which means your click event is also removed. Using 2 classes can remedy this.

**Javascript**

```
$(document).on('click', '.item', function() {
   $('.item').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected'); //add class to the clicked control
});
```

**Html**

```
<div id="resource">
   <div class="item">test</div>
   <div class="item">test</div>
</div>
```